Class "LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent" not found
i have an error when i hosting on server side , please help me
i user composer require wire-elements/modal
Class "LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent" not found
Class "LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent" not found
Class "LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent" not found
Class "LivewireUI\Modal\ModalComponent" not found

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
